# angular typescript syntax how to access return data with two aggregated objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been stuck on this typescript syntax where a WebAPI is returning a DTO with two objects. The following returning object is:

```
{
  "userList": [{
      "id": 1,
      "firstNm": "John",
      "lastNm": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstNm": "Jim",
      "lastNm": "Doe"
    }
  ],
  "selectedIds": [158, 155]
}
```

In my Angular TS code, I got the following code
In my declaration, I tried declaring `users` as `any[]` but
the CLI compiler highlights the usersList property in red citing the 'usersList' is not a member of the type of `any[]`.

I also tried declaring an interface of User with `memberList: any[]` but got the same error message. So when defining `users: any[]` and `User[]`, I am getting the same message.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

```
getUsers() {
  this.meetingService.GetCommitteeMembersAsync(this.request.meetingId)
    .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      var _test = data;
      this.users = _test.userList;
    });
}
```

Comment: If its starts by {, it's an object. if it starts by [, it's an array. It starts by {, so it's an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` will be of type `ComitteeMembersData`, and users will be `UserList`

```
users: UserList[]; // or ReadonlyArray<UserList>
...
.subscribe((data: ComitteeMembersData) => {
 // do something in here
}



export interface ComitteeMembersData{
    userList:    UserList[];
    selectedIds: number[];
}

export interface UserList {
    id:      number;
    firstNm: string;
    lastNm:  string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drenai. I understand typescript better now.

Answer (score -1):

The data that you're going to get is of the following format:

```
{
  "userList": [{
      "id": 1,
      "firstNm": "John",
      "lastNm": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstNm": "Jim",
      "lastNm": "Doe"
    }
  ],
  "selectedIds": [158, 155]
}
```

It can basically be of type `any` and not an `any[]`. `data.userList` however can be an `any[]`. So to fix the issue, just do this:

```
users: any[];
...
getUsers() {
  this.meetingService.GetCommitteeMembersAsync(this.request.meetingId)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.users = data.userList;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please at least have some courtesy to justify your downvote?